# Vuejs v-for performance issue after using webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-reactivity

I've been using a data table component I created years ago that renders a 2 dimensional array. I'm able to sort, paginate, filter columns. The whole thing works really fast. Lately I ventured into using webpack and creating a proper .vue component for my data table. Same code mind you but now the performance is much much slower performing sorts, paging and filtering. Is there something with webpack that causes the reactivity performance to drop considerably?

Simple code sample --

```
<table>
  <tr v-for="row in pagedData">
    <td v-for="column in columns">
      {{row[column.property]}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem had to do with Google Chrome. I exhausted every avenue (learned a lot more about the virtual DOM than I probably needed to) I tried the pages on Edge and Firefox which showed no delay. A quick reinstall of Chrome fixed this problem. Just a note I did read [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/common-mistakes-to-avoid-while-working-with-vue-js-10e0b130925b/) that using vue SFC's does incur a performance penalty since compilation occurs during runtime. Could be I'm misunderstanding what the sentence meant.